# Possible to attach event handler to listview('refresh') in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a listview that I'd like to bind a callback to after I call `listview('refresh')`.

In the optimal case I'd love to do something like this:

```coffee-script
listviews = $('[data-role="listview"]').live 'refresh', -> Console.log "Listview refresh"
```

I haven't found anything in the docs that say you can do anything like this, so I was thinking it could be possible to perhaps listen for DOM change events though the only thing I found is an event called `DOMNodeInserted` but support doesn't seem to be there on every browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refresh the listview yourself, so why not put an additional call in your code like that:

```
$whatever.listview('refresh').trigger('IrefreshAlistview');
```

Comment: I'm essentially doing this right now.  I was thinking that it might already be possible to listen for events that occur on the listviews instead of what I've done currently.

Comment: That would be a bit too much if everything caused an event to dispatch. It's not that lightweight so you don't want too many of them.